# Database Connection Security: Best practices to protect connection info in scripts?

Tags: php, database, security, authentication

I am developing a web application that will require use of a MySQL database from within different scripts in both PHP and JavaScript. I'm used to the "standard" concept of connecting to the db `mysql_connect("host", "username", "password")` but I am wondering how to keep these strings away from prying eyes. My assumption is that if a scripts contained the connection info, then that can then be used to get into the db itself and wreak havoc with user info and other important data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: JavaScript is not connecting to the database server directly, is it?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of ajax. Granted my knowledge of how that works is minimal at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the required permissons, try to save your connection information in environment variables, connect using them, then unset them.

I remember coming across this in some books and online resources, but currently first few Google pages return nothing on this.

First, set up two environment variables like `PHP_MYSQL_USER` and `PHP_MYSQL_PWD` outside PHP. Note that you may need to restart your web server, or even your OS in order them to be active.

Then, in PHP:

```
mysql_connect('localhost', getenv('PHP_MYSQL_USER'), getenv('PHP_MYSQL_PWD'));
putenv('PHP_MYSQL_USER=');
putenv('PHP_MYSQL_PWD=');
```

`putenv`'s are somewhat optional, if you include insecure third party or user scripts etc in your system, by using them you make the env. variables unavailable for the rest of the execution.

By using this approach, even if someone gets hold of your script, they won't know your db credentials. But keep in mind that if anyone gets to upload a script/shell into your server, they still will be able to see these variables. You can keep your upload directories in completely different areas where PHP is not executable, and/or with lower permisions. It is essential that you check the security of your uploads, for this mechanism and for any other server thing.

And as a side note, please take a look at [PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of using bad ol' `mysql_connect()`. You can search for innumerable reasons for this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll dig deeper into this. It should be a bit easier now that I have a reference point :)

Comment: I voted it down, because hiding things in environment variables is actually worse than storing them cleartext in files.  Files at least have ownerships/permissions to protect them.  Environment variables are dangerous because of subshells inheriting them, so other programs might have access to them with you knowing.  If your user/db/pass is available to apache as environment vars, ALL your pages have access to them, and they dont need to.  That's major potential for information leakage if any page has a security flaw.

Comment: Not all environment variables are accessible to all users. Of course, if one is going to use this approach, (s)he has to know about sudo, env. var.s, status of the env. var.s during execution and security in general. Moreover, if one is able to change env. variables, I assume that (s)he is at least in a dedicated/vps server environment, and has control over all of the files.

And if there are more than one server, they must be protected at a different level like firewalls etc.

Answer (score 0):

If someone has access to the source code of your scripts to see those passwords you are already in big trouble.  Make sure those scripts have the right file permissions and such (ie. only readable by those that need it).